# How many combinations to break a monoalphabetic substitution

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> Let a language $\Sigma$ have 16 letters, we have a message in that language that was encrypted using monoalphabetic substitution (a permutation of the alphabet) and we want to break it.
>
> We also noticed the message uses only 10 letters from $\Sigma$. How many tries will it take on average to break using brute force? (or how many possible combinations there are?)

I think the total is ${16 \choose 10}10!$

${16 \choose 10}$ choose a subset of letters

$10!$ is a permutation of those letters

But don't we need to consider the length of the message as well? (it wasn't mentioned in the question)

Comment: We don't. The number you gave is the total number of ways to decrypt the given word which is independent of the length of the word since if you changed the letters $a$ and $b$ for example, you decrypt the words $ab$ and $aabb$ just the same, namely $ba$ and $bbaa$.

Comment: Once you choose a trial substitution, the length of the message doesn’t affect how you complete the trial decipherment. The *only* effect that the length has is on how sure you can be that you’ve found the correct decipherment: a short message can yield sensible decipherments for more than one substitution, while a long one almost certainly can’t.